# Recorrer json con jquery y armar tabla html

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

obtengo un json como respuesta de una consulta a mi base de datos y dentro del json traigo un array con la siguiente información.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora cuando recorro ese array me esta duplicando el primer registro como se muestra en la imagen arriba.

el código que estoy usando es el siguiente.

```
function cargaInversionitas(items) {            
        $('#TablaSocios > tbody').empty();
        var item_add = '';                     
        console.log(items);

        items.forEach(function (item) {
            item_add += '<tr class="itemSocio">';
            item_add += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control Apellidos" value=' + item.Apellidos + '></td>';
            item_add += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control Nombres" value=' + item.Nombres + '></td>';
            item_add += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control Porcentaje" value=' + item.Porcentaje + '></td>';
            item_add += '<td class="tb-col-action text-center"><a href="#" class="link-cross me-sm-n1 removerSocio"><em class="icon ni ni-cross"></em></a></td>';
            item_add += '</tr>';
            $('#TablaSocios > tbody').append(item_add);
        })

    }
```

podrían apoyarme para saber cual es la problemática.

Answer (score 1):

Debes limpiar la variable `item_add` después de cada iteración, de lo contrario, acumulará los valores del ciclo anterior.

Colócala dentro del `forEach` o bien resetéala a una cadena vacía al final de cada ciclo (después de ejecutar `$('#TablaSocios > tbody').append(item_add);`).

```
function cargaInversionitas(items) {            
        $('#TablaSocios > tbody').empty();                     
        console.log(items);

        items.forEach(function (item) {
            var item_add = '';
            item_add += '<tr class="itemSocio">';
            item_add += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control Apellidos" value=' + item.Apellidos + '></td>';
            item_add += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control Nombres" value=' + item.Nombres + '></td>';
            item_add += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control Porcentaje" value=' + item.Porcentaje + '></td>';
            item_add += '<td class="tb-col-action text-center"><a href="#" class="link-cross me-sm-n1 removerSocio"><em class="icon ni ni-cross"></em></a></td>';
            item_add += '</tr>';
            $('#TablaSocios > tbody').append(item_add);
        })

    }
```

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias, la verdad no me habia dado cuenta jejeje

Comment: Marca la respuesta como aceptada, dale click en el check del costado. Saludos.